# How to allow third party cookies from incognito mood for iframe?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cookies, iframe, next.js

I have integrated a Next js form deployed on Netlify in React js project using Iframe, But i got this error

Error Message

[image: 1]

In console i got this error
"Uncaught DOMException: Failed to read the 'localStorage' property from 'Window': Access is denied for this document."
that's because iframe is not able to access Cookies in Incognito mood because browser disabled third party cookies in Private mood.

Is there any way a user can enable cookies without going to browser settings (because this is not user friendly behavior if every user has to go to settings to enable cookies) or any other better solution ?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot enable cookies from the code.

But you can check and show some information to the user that cookies are disabled please enable them like that.

```
function areCookiesEnabled() {
    var cookieEnabled = navigator.cookieEnabled;

    // When cookieEnabled flag is present and false then cookies are disabled.
    if (cookieEnabled === false) {
        return false;
    }

    // try to set a test cookie if we can't see any cookies and we're using 
    // either a browser that doesn't support navigator.cookieEnabled
    // or IE (which always returns true for navigator.cookieEnabled)
    if (!document.cookie && (cookieEnabled === null || /*@cc_on!@*/false))
    {
        document.cookie = "testcookie=1";

        if (!document.cookie) {
            return false;
        } else {
            document.cookie = "testcookie=; expires=" + new Date(0).toUTCString();
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```